# Constrain which relationship models are returned on whereHas

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

An example from the documentation:

```php
$posts = App\Post::whereHas('comments', function ($query) {
    $query->where('content', 'like', 'foo%');
})->get();
```

This will look for posts that has at least one comment with `foo`. It will return the post model with *all* comments. Is there a way to restrict this to return post model and related comments that only have `foo`?

I'm aware we can loop through `$posts` with a conditional later on but I'm looking for a solution via the query builder if possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the docs:

https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-relationships#constraining-eager-loads

```php
$users = App\User::with(['posts' => function ($query) {
    $query->where('title', 'like', '%first%');
}])->get();
```

---

Edit, the other answer is correct.. you should add it to you actual query, not just replace it as i suggested first:

So, from your example it would look like this:

```php
$posts = App\Post::with('comments', function ($query) {
    $query->where('content', 'like', 'foo%');
})->whereHas('comments', function ($query) {
    $query->where('content', 'like', 'foo%');
})->get();
```

You could also just add a lazy loading after your query

```php
$posts->load(['comments' => function ($query) {
    $query->where('content', 'like', 'foo%');
}]);
```

Edit, solution suggested by @HelenChe (original asker), it's basically the same, useful if `with` and `wherehas` are going to have the same filter function.

```php
$posts = Post::whereHas('comments', $filter = function ($query) { 
    $query->where('content', 'like', 'foo%'); 
})->with(['comments' => $filter])->get();
```

Comment: Thanks for linking to documentation. I might have a cleaner solution: `$posts = Post::whereHas('comments', $filter = function ($query) {
    $query->where('content', 'like', 'foo%');
})->with(['comments' => $filter])->get();`

Comment: Thanks for commenting! i added it to the answer

Answer (score 1):

If you want only the posts that has at least one comment with `foo` with those comments. you have to combine these two function, `whereHas()` and `with()`

```
$posts = App\Post::whereHas('comments', function ($query) {
        $query->where('content', 'like', 'foo%');
    })->get();
    ->with('comments', function ($query) {
        $query->where('content', 'like', 'foo%');
    })->get();
```